# SmartTarget content selection filter not working for multi-value field

Tags: smarttarget

I have a promotion where I select content from a folder and filter it by a component field value, which is selected from a list (Games, Girls or Golf). It all works fine when there is a single value in the component, but if I add additional values, the content filter only seems to act on the first value, so I never see the content when I provide a filter value equal to the second value in the component field.

I see the same behaviour when I have a static 'custom' filter value (eg "Golf") or a dynamic filter value passed into the query. If I rearrange values in the source XML, save and publish it seems to also only index the first value.

Any ideas how to get this working, or is this a bug/feature?

Answer (score 1):

What type of operator do you use for content filtering, is it a "contains" or "does not contain"?

It looks like multi-value text fields are only covered for those two filter types.

http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-09B2E4B8-AA87-4B45-9EF8-FBC85C0BA16E

I can also suggest opening a ticket with Customer Support to see if the behavior can be replicated and then addressed further if needed.  Please add the specific product versions (eg. 2013 SP1 HR1 with ST 2014 SP1).

Comment: Interesting link - I only have an "is" operator, but that may be due to the fact that this is an additional field added during publishing, rather than a real CM field value - I will try it out with a real CM field to see if that makes a difference